# datepicker Error = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can't get jQueryUI datepicker option `beforeShowDay` to work.

I've tried different help topics I've found but I can't get it working.

I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

This is my JS. but it doesn't seems to work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var your_dates = [new Date(13, 5, 5), new Date(13, 5, 10)];
    jQuery("div#event-calender").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            if (jQuery.inArray(date.toString(), your_dates) != -1) {
                return [true, 'highlight'];
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to always return an array, not just when a condition matches.

From the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay):

> beforeShowDay
>
> Type: Function( Date date )
>
> A function that takes a date as a parameter **and must return an array**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var your_dates = [new Date(13, 5, 5), new Date(13, 5, 10)];
    jQuery("div#event-calender").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var arr;
            if (jQuery.inArray(date.toString(), your_dates) != -1) {
                arr = [true, 'highlight'];
            }else {
                arr = [true, ''];
            }
            return arr;
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fuV83/)

Comment: Thank you, quite an obvious issue, saved me some debug time to actually find where the issue was since js error didn't show me the exact row of the file +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

> **beforeShowDay**
>   A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array
>   with:
>
> - true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable a CSS
> - class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default
> - presentation an optional popup tooltip for this date
>
> The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is
>   displayed

Change your `beforeShowDay` to

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(date.toString(), your_dates) != -1) {
        return [true, 'highlight'];
    } else {
        return [true, ''];
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Either change `your_dates` to

```
var your_dates = [new Date(2013,5,5).toString(), new Date(2013,5,10).toString()];
```

or use something like this instead of `jQuery.inArray(...)`

```
var found = your_dates.filter(function(d) {
                return date.getTime() === d.getTime();
            }).length > 0;

return [true, (found ? 'highlight' : '')];
```

Comment: That helped thanks. But i all the elements get's "not-highlighted". Do you know what this problem is? Should I choose some other Date format?

Comment: Is this really the date you expect `new Date(13, 5, 5) == "05. June, 1913"` ?

Comment: No, my array looks like this now

<code>var your_dates = [new Date(2013,05,05), new Date(2013,05,10)];</code>

But still no one gets the highlight class