# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following jQuery code for datepicker and I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. 
I want to do some computations in the beforeShowDay callback but because of this error I'm unable to do so. I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery-ui 1.10.4

I found a similar question but none of the solutions seems to be working:

[datepicker Error = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698368/datepicker-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inline_datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function(){
                fetch_time_slots($(this).datepicker("getDate"));
            },
            beforeShowDay: function(date){
                console.log(date)
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Which line is the error thrown on?  Or is it within the JQueryUI code that the error is thrown? S JSFiddle would be useful if you could knock one up?

Comment: there you go http://jsfiddle.net/j7d39/

Answer (score 5):

It looks to be the same problem as your linked question:

You need to return an array from the `beforeShowDay` callback.

I've updated the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j7d39/2/) with this:

```
$("#inlinedatepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            console.log(date);
            return [true,""];
        }
});
```

and it logs all the dates without throwing the Uncaught TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `return` in `beforeShowDay` function. Try modifying `beforeShowDay` function as follows.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){
console.log(date);
return [true, "test", "test"];
}
```

Please check this jQuery documentation for [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

Answer (score 0):

**beforeShowDay**

> Type: Function( Date date )
>
> Default: null
>
> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
>
> **[0]**: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
>
> **[1]**: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
>
> **[2]**: an optional popup tooltip for this date
>
> The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        var day = date.getDate();
                        var month = date.getMonth();
                        if ( day == 30 || day == 31 ) {$("#purchasedate").val(""); return [false];}
                        else{ return [true,""];}
                        },
```